# Why is it impossible to root a whole equation

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, self-learning

I have this equation:

$x^2+(x-7)^2=13^2$

Why can't squaring the whole equation be used to solve it?

$\sqrt{x^2+(x-7)^2=13^2}\equiv x+x-7=13$

My question is merely asking when square cannot be used to solve an equation.

Comment: In general, $\sqrt{a+b} \not= \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: If you attempt to solve it that way, you get that $x = 10$ is a solution. Yet $10^2 + (10-7)^2 \neq 13^2$. So there is an error in your thought process, and anomaly has identified it.

Comment: if $\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt {a} + \sqrt{b} $ then $ a + b = a + b +2\sqrt{ab} \implies a\hspace{1 mm} or\hspace{1 mm}  b = 0$

Comment: You are not squaring, you are taking the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your approach, we would get $x=10$.

But neither $10^2+3^2=13^2$, nor $\sqrt{10^2+3^2}=13$.

You can indeed "square root" the equation (with some care for the signs), but you may not "square root" a sum.

Indeed, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\ne a^2+b^2$ so that $a+b\ne\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: So I take it as a general rule, squaring an equation is only possible when there are only single members on both sides.

Comment: Even then it's not allowed. Consider $$(1- x^2)^2 = 15^2$$. Taking square roots of both sides gets $1 - x^2 = 15$, so $x^2 = -14$ and there's no solution. But that's wrong, for $x = 4$ IS a solution: $(1 - 4^2)^2 = (-15)^2 = 15^2$.

Comment: @JohnHughes: this is why I specified "with some care for the signs".

Comment: I saw that and appreciated it...but Shimmy's comment suggested to me that your remark somehow slipped past without being noticed (or at least without being understood), so a concrete example seemed like a Good Thing.